# www and non www redirection issue. Somebody help!

Tags: redirect

I have a website ABC.com the thing is that www.ABC.com is working while ABC.com is not. I set up domain forwarding for both to point to www.ABC.com but the browser says its an infinite loop. So, I setup a subdomain in ABC.example.com and pointed both ABC.com and www.ABC.com to ABC.example.com with the URL masked. Will there be any problems from SE point of view? Right now it seems to be working fine. Also I absolutely dont want my visitors to know that it is hosted in example.com As this is a custom domain issue I dont have .htaccess or 301 redirect permissions

Answer (score 3):

> I set up domain forwarding for both to point to www.ABC.com but the browser says its an infinite loop

You probably don't want www.ABC.com to forward to www.ABC.com since yes, that is an infinite loop indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be re-directing, contact your host and ask where you find the setting that automatically appends the URL with www in the event of someone just typing (in your case) ABC.com - this is a prominent feature of most hosting software and should be enabled by default.